# OpenCV Android converting c++ to java

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have the following code in c++:

```
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
  vector<vector<Point>> contours;
 findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
double refArea = 0;
if(hierarchy.size() > 0) {
  int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
  //do other stuff
  for(int i = 0; i >= 0; i = hierarchy[i][0]) {
     Moments moment = moments((Mat)contours[i]);
     double area = moment.m00;
     //do more stuff
  }
}
```

What is the best way to convert this to java for android opencv programming? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on what exactly 'hierarchy' is. Conversion depends critically on the types of things, not on their names.

Comment: Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

Comment: Is converting to Java a necessity ? I'd suggest you to take a look at JNI to to allow native C/C++ extensions to be developed for Java. Also, image processing operations will be much much slower than in C/C++